# temporal data fix

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

We messed up on application side and loaded some incorrect data in one column.. Now we need to fix this data.. Here is what we need to do.

```
Starttime                      Answertime

2012-08-30 00:40:40.000      2012-08-30 03:40:53.000
```

Answertime is almost 3 hour more than starttime which is incorrect. Now what we need to is find the difference of **seconds** between answertime and startime and add it to starttime. So for above 2012-08-30 **00:40:53.000** will be new answertime.

Kind of confused at the moment on how to do it. Using sql server 2008 R2

Comment: Is `Answertime` always off by 3 hours exactly? If so, that is a simple fix. If you go by seconds only, what happens when the minute is different for each value?

Comment: yep.. that's the question.. hour diff is not always 3 hours and need to account for minute diff too.

Comment: If you need to account for minute, then you need to account for hour diff too. And day, month, year :) E.g., `Starttime='2012-12-31 11:59:59'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
declare @t table (
  Starttime datetime,
  Answertime datetime);
insert @t values (
  '2012-08-30 00:40:40.000','2012-08-30 03:40:53.000'),(
  '2012-08-30 00:59:59.900','2012-08-30 03:00:03.000');

update @t set Answertime =
  case when dateadd(hh,datediff(hh,answertime,starttime),answertime) > starttime
       then dateadd(hh,datediff(hh,answertime,starttime),answertime)
       else dateadd(hh,datediff(hh,answertime,starttime)+1,answertime) end
where Answertime > DateAdd(hh,1,StartTime); -- more than 1 hour apart

select * from @T;

>>
STARTTIME                   ANSWERTIME
August, 30 2012 00:40:40    August, 30 2012 00:40:53
August, 30 2012 00:59:59    August, 30 2012 01:00:03
```

The gist of the answer is that leaving Minutes:Seconds.MilliSecs aside, the answertime is put into the same hour as the starttime. It also fixes edge cases like the 2nd row where the change makes it earlier than the starttime.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to ignore everything but seconds, but handle the case where the difference goes over a minute mark.

```
Update timetable set Answertime =
case when DatePart(ss,Answertime) >= DatePart(ss,Starttime) 
     then dateAdd(ss, DatePart(ss,Answertime)-DatePart(ss,starttime),Starttime)
else
     dateAdd(ss, 60+DatePart(ss,Answertime)-DatePart(ss,Starttime),Starttime)
end
```